# Applying css to sibling element when hovering

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an input box with a label. The label is inside the input box. I want the label to move above the input box when the input box is focused.

I think I need to use input:focus ~ label to focus the label when the input box is selected but I cannot get it to work.

html:

```
<div class="search-container">
  <form [formGroup]="SearchForm" (ngSubmit)="getWeatherFromCity(SearchForm.value)" name="SearchForm">
      <div class='city-input'>
      <label for="searchCity">City </label>
      <input class="form-input" formControlName="searchCity" id="searchCity">
    </div>
      <button class="button" title="Search">Search
      </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
.search-container{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;

  .city-input{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    input{
      border-radius: 10px;
      height: 2em;
      width: 17.5em;
      &:focus ~ label {
      transform: translateY(-30px);
      color: red
      }
    }
      label{
      transition: transform 0.5s;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  }
```

Please advise.

Cheers.

Comment: because label should be place after and not before

Comment: The general sibling combinator (`~`) will select every sibling _following_ the one referenced. As @TemaniAfif suggests, moving the `<label>` after the `<input>` will solve this.

Comment: Oh wow - thank you so much Temani. So the psuedo class (focus) must come before the element it is called on (label)?

Comment: Great - thanks for clearing that up @agrm!

Answer (score 0):

you can't select a previous element with just css afaik

you could use jQuery for this, kinda... [demo](https://codepen.io/_Odinh/pen/PQZvMM)

```
$( ".form-input" ).focus(function() {
  $(".form-input").prev("label").addClass("the-class-to-handle-the-transition");
});                     
$( ".form-input" ).focusout(function() {
  $(".form-input").prev("label").removeClass("the-class-to-handle-the-transition");
});
```